# Changing JLabel text changes distribution of space by GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a JFrame with GridBagLayout, which contains a JLabel and a JScrollPane. The JScrollPane contains a ScrollablePanel, which in turn contains a certain amount of DebugComponents. The DebugComponents maintain an aspect ratio that is derived from the height of the JScrollPane. The layout of the JFrame with the GridBagLayout fits well at the beginning.

Now, however, I use a MouseMotionListener that changes the text of the JLabel indirectly via a thread. If the mouse is over the DebugComponent, there is a text displayed. Otherwise the area is empty. When I move to the DebugComponent, however, the layout changes. If I move the mouse back and forth between DebugComponent and ScrollablePanel, the space used by the JScrollPane gets bigger and bigger. It only stops when there is only space for the text for the JLabel left.

The code is an abstraction of my problem. Except for the class for the ScrollablePanel ([get it here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/)), the code is complete.

```
package de.franken.debug;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DebugGUI {

    private static JLabel label;
    public static ScrollablePanel panel;

    /** Main method + GUI configuration */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // JFrame
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        panel = new ScrollablePanel(new GridLayout(1, 0)); // Panel containing DebugItems
        panel.setScrollableHeight(ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            panel.add(new DebugComponent(0.2));
        }
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weighty = 0.6;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); // ScrollPane containing Panel
        new SlideThread(pane);
        frame.add(pane, c);

        label = new JLabel("PLACEHOLDER"); // Label displaying String
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.weighty = 0.4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        frame.add(label, c);

        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /**
     * Change text of JLabel beneath ScrollablePane. -> Called by SlideThread
     * 
     * @param strg : the String to be displayed
     */
    public static void setPreview(String strg) {
        label.setText(strg);
    }

    static class DebugComponent extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4770356342749347317L;
        private double widthRatio;

        /**
         * JComponent as part of ScrollablePanel with constant dimension ratio
         * 
         * @param widthRatio : the ratio to be multiplied with height to get width
         */
        DebugComponent(double widthRatio) {
            this.widthRatio = widthRatio;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension parent = super.getSize();

            return new Dimension((int) (parent.height * widthRatio), parent.height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, (int) getPreferredSize().getWidth() - 1, (int) getPreferredSize().getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

    static class SlideThread extends Thread {
        private String strg = " ";

        SlideThread(JScrollPane pane) {
            pane.addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
            this.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sleep(45);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DebugGUI.setPreview(strg);
            }
        }

        // Show String during hovering
        MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                Component c = DebugGUI.panel.getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                if (c instanceof DebugComponent) {
                    strg = "Titel";
                } else {
                    strg = " ";
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Beware, Swing is NOT thread safe, you may encounter other issues with your use of Thread. Better to use a Swing Timer

Comment: I’d also be concerned about your use of static, dependency injection would be a better solution

Comment: *aspect ratio that is derived from the height of the JScrollPane.* - I would say the code is struggling because your components have a preferred size based on a dynamically change size of the DebugComponent since its size is based on the size of the scroll pane and the layout manager will then alter the size based on the "weightY" constraints used, which could then alter the preferred size again etc. Usually components have a fixed preferred size and THEN the layout manager will alter the actual size.

Comment: Also, `Dimension parent = super.getSize();` doesn't seem to make sense. It doesn't fix the probllem, If you want the parent size shouldn't you use: `getParent().getSize()` or maybe `SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass​(Class<?> c, Component comp)` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I do it the same way in another program and it works for me. The main task of the thread is to scroll the JScrollPane by hovering over it's left and right corners. This part isn't included here.

Comment: @camickr, the Scrollable Pane should fit the height and use the width it needs. Therefore I request the height of the parent. I changed super to getParent() but nothing changed. What do you suggest?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: camickr is right—the preferred size must not depend on the current size, because the current size is assigned by the parent layout, which will based that size on the preferred size.  In other words, preferred size determines current size, not the other way around.  When I removed that, the layout was stable.

Comment: *I do it the same way in another program and it works for me.* - All Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Yes, in most cases there will not be a problem but there is a chance of concurrency issues which can cause random bugs. Random bugs are almost impossible to debug. So follow Swing guidelines. Read the Swing tutorial on [Coincurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. In fact your entire [mre] should be changed to be created on the EDT.

Comment: *What do you suggest* - give your debug component a preferred height, not based on the parent size. The width would then be calculated as a ratio of the height. This is how Swing components work. Then when you create the frame you `pack()` the frame so all components are displayed at the preferred size. You might also need to write a custom layout manager for your panel that makes the component width a ratio of the height. This is how a GridLayout, for example works. The GridLayout adjusts the size of all components based on the size of the parent container.

Comment: @hinrich. *" I do it the same way in another program and it works for me"* - Just because it's worked before doesn't mean it will work in the future, Swing is simply NOT thread safe, so you're playing with fire, it might, it might not and when it doesn't it will do so randomly and produce inconsistent results, but if you're happy with it producing garbage randomly, that's up to you, you've been advised on what cause of action you could take to prevent it, it's up now up to you to decide whether to do it or not, just don't be surprised then next you post that code, you get told the same thing

Comment: I would also consider investing some kind of "overlay" workflow, where the "debug" label is decoupled from the other UI elements and is managed via a different layout process

Comment: In case you didn't understand by comment about creating a custom layout manager, there would be two steps involved. First you need to create your custom component with a well defined preferred size. You could do this with two parameters: 1) the preferred height 2) the width ratio. Then you override the `getPreferredSize()` method so calculate the preferred size based of the two parameter. You now have a component that can be used in any layout manager.

Comment: 2) Now you need a layout manager to preserve the width/height ratio. So the layout manager would divide the preferred height into the height of the panel. This value would be used to set the width of the component. The height would then be set to the height of the panel. You do this for all components on the panel. Then you set the location of each component. The preferred size of the panel would then be calculated based on the location and width of the last component.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. `SetPreferredSize()` actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

GridBagLayout accounts only for visible components, so when your JLabel is blank, the layout treats it as a no-dimension component and acts as if it doesn't actually exist.

There are a couple of things you can try to avoid this issue:

a) Make the JLabel's text blank, rather than empty, e.g. `myLabel.setText(" ")` rather than `myLabel.setText("")`;

b) Change the text's color to match the label's background color whenever there isn't supposed to be any text.

You may have some luck with putting the label into a BorderLayout within one cell of the GridBagLayout, in hopes that the "greedy" nature of the BorderLayout expands the component to take as much space as is available, but I haven't tried it myself, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I already use `label.setText(" ")` and even if I change the text between "Titel" and "letiT", the bug occurs.